# How can I create TableNameColumnName alias' for SELECT * statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I want to have the following output:

```
TableAColumn1 TableAColumn2 TableBColumn1 TableBColumn2
SomeValue     SomeValue     SomeValue     SomeValue
```

For the following statement:

```
SELECT * AS ...
FROM TableA,
     TableB
WHERE TableA.Column1 = TableB.Column1
```

Is this possible in SQL Server 2014? Is it possible to utilise INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS for what I want to achieve?

Comment: Isn't that you are using join? if Column1 in one table is PK and in another FK then above query should work except just select columns whihc you need rather than * and remove as.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick: using `select *` / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) by Aaron Bertrand might be worth reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a list of columns with this query:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ','+ a.TABLE_NAME + '.' + a.COLUMN_NAME + ' AS ' +a.TABLE_NAME + a.COLUMN_NAME
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
              WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '')
```